# Magento : Overriding Config Controller?

Tags: magento, config

Can any one please tell me how to override `config` controller in magento. I have attatched my config  code below :

```
<config>
<modules>
    <Adodis_Themechooser>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Adodis_Themechooser>
</modules>
    <adminhtml>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <all>
                <title>Allow Everything</title>
            </all>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <Adodis_Themechooser>
                        <title>Themechooser Module</title>
                        <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                    </Adodis_Themechooser>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    <themechooser>
                                        <title>Themechooser</title>
                                    </themechooser>
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</adminhtml> 
<global>


            <adminhtml> 
                 <rewrite>
                    <themechooser_config>
                        <from><![CDATA[#^/admin/system_config/#]]></from>
                        <to>/themechooser/config/</to>
                    </themechooser_config>
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>

    <models>
        <themechooser>
            <class>Adodis_Themechooser_Model</class>
        </themechooser>
    </models>
    <helpers>
        <themechooser>
            <class>Adodis_Themechooser_Helper</class>
        </themechooser>
    </helpers>
 </global>  
 </config>
```

Comment: If you're trying to add a section to the config you don't need to override the controller at all. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: @clockworkgeek : Here is what i am trying to do,

1) i have done module to choose theme once the theme is chosen it will be applied on frontend




2) i have made some modification in saveaction() controller in mage/adminhtml/controllers/system/ConfigController.php ,changes i have made in above file working perfectly ,but i need to make a controller in my module that overrides config controller.this is what i am trying to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An override of the config controller means you will be dealing with all presses of the Save Config button, not just your own `themechooser` page. That method of override means that no other module could ever make a compatible override of their own, and the "from/to" syntax is outdated anyway. Also an override is not needed at all, you're only interested in the saving of one field and that can be found through a [backend_model](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/admin/xml_structure_for_admin_configurations#backend_model).

Your module probably has an `etc/system.xml` file,

```
<config>
    <sections>
        <themechooser>
            <groups>
                <themechooser>
                    <fields>
                        <example translate="label">
                            <label>This is a text field</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <backend_model>themechooser/config_example</backend_model>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        </example>
                    </fields>
                </themechooser>
            </groups>
        </themechooser>
    </sections>
</config>
```

Note the backend_model. Now make the class that fits `themechooser/config_example`,

```
class Adodis_Themechooser_Model_Config_Example extends Mage_Core_Model_Config_Data {

    protected function _afterSave() {
        $value = $this->getValue();
        // $value is the text in the text field
    }

}
```

All that remains is to use `$value` to set the frontend theme. The field can be any type, it does not have to be text.

Comment: Hi,
Thank you for your kind reply,
Probably this module is made to choose the list of available theme
user will not have access to the themes through FTP they are forced to choose from dropdown,
So text field is useless
To manage this i am using dropdown..
i am facing another problem , values saved from this module disappears when we perform another saveaction.right now i have made changes dirctly to Configcontroller.php can you please tell me that how to do it in a proper way,i am a begginer in making modules in magento so please apologize ,if there is any wrong in my question,

Comment: Hai thank you for your help. The problem is solved. I followed the steps you're told to me. And, i've completed the module. Million Thanks. Stackoverflow Rockzzzzzzzz..